# Is there a way to import custom shapefiles for use with Gisgraphy?

Tags: gisgraphy

I installed gisgraphy and looked at the data importer wizard -- it only has two options: Import Geonames and/or Import OpenStreetMap.

I want to make Gisgraphy work with shapefiles.  Since Gisgraphy uses PostGIS I was wondering; Is there a way to import shapefiles into PostGres/PostGIS directly and have it work with Gisgraphy?

Comment: A simple internet search brings up many hits on how to import shapefiles into PostGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shape files schema are all differents. You first have to convert your .shp in a sql files, import it and then export it to the gisgraphy format. It can be a simple insert into Gisgraphy table (select fields1, fields2 from shptable).